# What are the ways to switch between components in a chrome extension in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router

What are the ways to switch between components in a chrome extension in React? I tried use react-router-dom, but it doesn't work. Expecteting effect: click link `Details` open component `Details`

```
<Router history={history}>
   <Link to="/">Details</Link>
   <Route path='/' component={Details}/>
</Router>
```

Can anyone explain to me how to use: hash and memory history?

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zdhfub

```
class Details extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render() {

    return (  
      <div>
        <p>
            Here is description
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
           <Link to="/">Details</Link>
          <Route path='/' component={Details}/>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your `Route`,

```
<Route path='/' component={Details}/>
```

When your project run's, by default it will load the component from `path='/'`, so in your case `Details` component is by default getting loaded.

To see the actual routing effect, create `Routes` file seperatly and then import that file in `App` component

```
<div>
  <Router history={history}>
     <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
     <Route path='/details' component={Details} />
  </Router>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tqfxfm)

Comment: Is it possible for the `Details` component to replace the` App` component in the view? I want to see only component `Details`, without` This is from App Details`

Comment: I have a strange error:  `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

Comment: Have you written any `Link` outside of `Routes` like in `App.js` file before or after `<Routes />` component? The error is because `Link` is a part of `Router` like we write `<Route />` in `Router`. Where you are including `<Routes/>` component in that file don't add any `Link` tag.

Comment: `App.js` file should only contain `<Routes />`, and move your other code to main component i.e. `ItemDetails` component

Comment: After segragating the component now its working fine, the issue is the cache.